# Sort and change index numbers in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, sorting

I have some files that start with an index number similar to this:

```
(1) etc
(2) etc
(3) etc
```

I want to add lines between and make Notepad++ to change index numbers automatically. So for example if I add a new line after `(1)` and put the index to `(2)`, then the older `(2)` should change to `(3)` and `(3)` to `(4)`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can't do this automatically with Notepad.
I suggest that you copy-paste data to Excel and modify it there and copy-paste back if you need.
You can use "Text to Columns" option in excel to split data in columns and then apply formula to the numbered column to increase values.

Comment: I think formatting of text is in a way that makes it very hard to do so, but i will give it a try thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)

Copy this code and save the file (for example `replace.py`):

```
import re

def calculate(match):
    return str(int(match.group(1))+1)

editor.rereplace('(?<=^\()(\d+)(?=\))', calculate)
```

- Open the file you want to change
- Run the script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> replace)
- Done

**Regex explanation:**

```
(?<=^\()    # positive lookbehind, 
               # make sure we have an opening parenthesis (at the beginning of line) before
(\d+)       # group 1,, 1 or more digits
(?=\))      # positive lookahead, make sure we have a closing parenthesis after
```

**Result for given example:**

[image]

Comment: Thank You, this is very helpful, is it possible to make it break after space? so if there is another (x) in same line it won't increase it's number. i am sorry i am very bad at Re i can't change it my self.

Comment: @justaguest123: Just change the regex to: `^(?<=\()(\d+)(?=\))`, note the caret `^` at the beginning, it stands for `beginning of line`

Comment: That seems to make some sort of problem cause script doesn't work at all.

Comment: @justaguest123: Sorry, I've made a typo, it should be: `(?<=^\()(\d+)(?=\))`, the carret is **inside** the lookbehind.

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks.